# XSLT 1.0 different namespace uri in input files

Tags: namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to write xslt transformation for xml files and I have a problem with namespace URI-s. Input files has for the same namespace (gml) different URI-s and than it results in "double" namespace declaration - one in root element with one URI value and than in some inline elements with another URI value. I think real example will shows more:
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gfc="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gfc" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/draft-schemas/inspire-md-schemas-temp/apiso-inspire/apiso-inspire.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<!-- globálne   premenné    -->

<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'aábcdefghíijklmnňopqrstuúvwxyžz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'AÁBCDEFGHIÍJKLMNŇOPQRSTUÚVWXYŽZ'" />
<!-- hierarchyLevel -->
<xsl:variable name="hierarchyLevel">
    <xsl:if test="//gmd:hierarchyLevel/gmd:MD_ScopeCode/@codeListValue = 'service'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'service'" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>  

<!-- serviceType -->
<xsl:variable name="serviceType">
    <xsl:value-of select="//gmd:identificationInfo/srv:SV_ServiceIdentification/srv:serviceType/gco:LocalName/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Templates -->

<!-- Skopirovanie celeho mtd zaznamu -->

<xsl:template name="HeaderTemplate" match="@* | node()">        
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- úprava referencii na schemy -->
<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
<xsl:template name="Namespaces" match="//gmd:MD_Metadata">
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=" $hierarchyLevel = 'service'">                
            <gmd:MD_Metadata  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/draft-schemas/inspire-md-schemas-temp/apiso-inspire/apiso-inspire.xsd">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </gmd:MD_Metadata>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <gmd:MD_Metadata   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/draft-schemas/inspire-md-schemas-temp/apiso-inspire/apiso-inspire.xsd">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </gmd:MD_Metadata>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Kľúčové slová INSPIRE GEMET  -->
<xsl:template match="//gmd:descriptiveKeywords/gmd:MD_Keywords[gmd:thesaurusName/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString[starts-with(.,'GEMET - INSPIRE themes')]]">
    <gmd:MD_Keywords>
        <xsl:for-each select="gmd:keyword">
            <gmd:keyword>
                <xsl:if test="gco:CharacterString = 'Atmospheric conditions'">
                    <gmx:Anchor xlink:href="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/theme/ac">Atmosférické podmienky</gmx:Anchor>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="gco:CharacterString = 'Atmosférické podmienky'">
                    <gmx:Anchor xlink:href="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/theme/ac">Atmosférické podmienky</gmx:Anchor>
                </xsl:if>
                </gmd:keyword>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <gmd:thesaurusName>
            <gmd:CI_Citation>
                <gmd:title>
                    <gmx:Anchor xlink:href="https://www.eionet.europa.eu/gemet/it/inspire-themes/">GEMET - INSPIRE themes, version 1.0</gmx:Anchor>
                </gmd:title>
                <gmd:date>
                    <gmd:CI_Date>
                        <gmd:date>
                            <gco:Date>2008-06-01</gco:Date>
                        </gmd:date>
                        <gmd:dateType>
                            <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="publication"/>
                        </gmd:dateType>
                    </gmd:CI_Date>
                </gmd:date>
            </gmd:CI_Citation>
        </gmd:thesaurusName>
    </gmd:MD_Keywords>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input files 1 which has namespace declaration for gml same as XSLT xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" :

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/draft-schemas/inspire-md-schemas-temp/apiso-inspire/apiso-inspire.xsd">
<gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/gmd/17316219/SK_UGKK_ZBGIS_INSPIRE_TN</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:fileIdentifier>
<gmd:language>
    <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="slo">slo</gmd:LanguageCode>
</gmd:language>
<gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset">dataset</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
<gmd:contact>
    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        <gmd:organisationName>
            <gco:CharacterString>Geodetický a kartografický ústav Bratislava (GKÚ)</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:organisationName>            
        <gmd:role>
            <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="pointOfContact">pointOfContact</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
        </gmd:role>
    </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
</gmd:contact>
<gmd:dateStamp>
    <gco:Date>2019-12-09</gco:Date>
</gmd:dateStamp>
<gmd:metadataStandardName>
    <gco:CharacterString>ISO19115 - profil ZBGIS</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:metadataStandardName>
<gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
    <gco:CharacterString>2003/Cor.1:2006</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:metadataStandardVersion>    
<gmd:identificationInfo>
    <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
        <gmd:citation>
            <gmd:CI_Citation>
                <gmd:title>
                    <gco:CharacterString>INSPIRE - Dopravné siete</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:title>
                <gmd:date>
                    <gmd:CI_Date>
                        <gmd:date>
                            <gco:Date>2017-11-23</gco:Date>
                        </gmd:date>
                        <gmd:dateType>
                            <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="revision">revision</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
                        </gmd:dateType>
                    </gmd:CI_Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:identifier>
                    <gmd:MD_Identifier>
                        <gmd:code>
                            <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/dat/17316219/SK_UGKK_ZBGIS_INSPIRE_TN</gco:CharacterString>
                        </gmd:code>
                    </gmd:MD_Identifier>
                </gmd:identifier>
            </gmd:CI_Citation>
        </gmd:citation>
        <gmd:abstract>
            <gco:CharacterString>Dátová sada INSPIRE - Dopravné siete obsahuje vybrané triedy objektov zo ZBGIS, ktoré patria pod dátovú špecifikáciu INSPIRE Transport Networks. Predmetom tejto INSPIRE témy sú siete cestnej, železničnej, leteckej a vodnej dopravy a súvisiaca infraštruktúra.</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:abstract>
        <gmd:pointOfContact>
            <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
                <gmd:organisationName>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Geodetický a kartografický ústav Bratislava (GKÚ)</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:organisationName>                    
                <gmd:role>
                    <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="author">author</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
                </gmd:role>
            </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        </gmd:pointOfContact>            
        <gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
            <gmd:MD_Keywords>
                <gmd:keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>doprava</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:keyword>                   
            </gmd:MD_Keywords>
        </gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
        <gmd:spatialRepresentationType>
            <gmd:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode" codeListValue="vector">vector</gmd:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode>
        </gmd:spatialRepresentationType>
        <gmd:spatialResolution>
            <gmd:MD_Resolution>
                <gmd:equivalentScale>
                    <gmd:MD_RepresentativeFraction>
                        <gmd:denominator>
                            <gco:Integer>10000</gco:Integer>
                        </gmd:denominator>
                    </gmd:MD_RepresentativeFraction>
                </gmd:equivalentScale>
            </gmd:MD_Resolution>
        </gmd:spatialResolution>
        <gmd:language>
            <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="slo">slo</gmd:LanguageCode>
        </gmd:language>
        <gmd:characterSet>
            <gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode" codeListValue="utf8">utf8</gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode>
        </gmd:characterSet>
        <gmd:topicCategory>
            <gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode>transportation</gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode>
        </gmd:topicCategory>
        <gmd:extent>
            <gmd:EX_Extent>
                <gmd:description>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Územie celej Slovenskej republiky.</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:description>
                <gmd:geographicElement>
                    <gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                        <gmd:extentTypeCode>
                            <gco:Boolean>true</gco:Boolean>
                        </gmd:extentTypeCode>
                        <gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>16.83</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                        <gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>22.57</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                        <gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>47.73</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                        <gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>49.61</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                    </gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                </gmd:geographicElement>
            </gmd:EX_Extent>
        </gmd:extent>
        <gmd:extent>
            <gmd:EX_Extent>
                <gmd:temporalElement>
                    <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
                        <gmd:extent>
                            <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="ID5etd6b9e-f6be-4a4d-b558-1b5c565ba0fe" xsi:type="gml:TimePeriodType">
                                <gml:beginPosition>2020-01-01</gml:beginPosition>
                                <gml:endPosition>2020-02-02</gml:endPosition>
                            </gml:TimePeriod>
                        </gmd:extent>
                    </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
                </gmd:temporalElement>
            </gmd:EX_Extent>
        </gmd:extent>
    </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
</gmd:identificationInfo></gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

Second input files which has different uri value for gml namespace xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" :

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/metadataEntity.xsd">
<gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/gmd/42181810/4E93317B0429510DE0530210000A9EA5</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:fileIdentifier>
<gmd:language>
    <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="slo">slo</gmd:LanguageCode>
</gmd:language>    
<gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset">dataset</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
<gmd:contact>
    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        <gmd:individualName>
            <gco:CharacterString>Martin Tuchyňa</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:individualName>
        <gmd:organisationName>
            <gco:CharacterString>Ministerstvo životného prostredia Slovenskej republiky</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:organisationName>            
        <gmd:role>
            <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="pointOfContact">pointOfContact</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
        </gmd:role>
    </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
</gmd:contact>
<gmd:dateStamp>
    <gco:Date>2017-05-03</gco:Date>
</gmd:dateStamp>
<gmd:metadataStandardName>
    <gco:CharacterString>ISO 19115</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:metadataStandardName>
<gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
    <gco:CharacterString>2003/Cor.1:2006, Slovenský národný metaúdajový profil</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:metadataStandardVersion>    
<gmd:identificationInfo>
    <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
        <gmd:citation>
            <gmd:CI_Citation>
                <gmd:title>
                    <gco:CharacterString>INSPIRE PD 1,01 Zóny hodnotenia a riadenia kvality ovzdušia, Aglomerácie  hodnotenia a riadenia kvality ovzdušia</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:title>
                <gmd:date>
                    <gmd:CI_Date>
                        <gmd:date>
                            <gco:Date>2017-05-01</gco:Date>
                        </gmd:date>
                        <gmd:dateType>
                            <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="creation">creation</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
                        </gmd:dateType>
                    </gmd:CI_Date>
                </gmd:date>
                <gmd:identifier>
                    <gmd:RS_Identifier>
                        <gmd:code>
                            <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/dat/42181810/4E93317B0429510DE0530210000A9EA5</gco:CharacterString>
                        </gmd:code>
                        <gmd:codeSpace>
                            <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/dat/42181810/</gco:CharacterString>
                        </gmd:codeSpace>
                    </gmd:RS_Identifier>
                </gmd:identifier>
            </gmd:CI_Citation>
        </gmd:citation>
        <gmd:abstract>
            <gco:CharacterString>Smernica Európskeho Parlamentu a Rady 2008/50/ES z 21. mája 2008 o kvalite okolitého ovzdušia a čistejšom ovzduší v Európe (vrátane implementácie Rozhodnutia 20111/850/EU);Referencia v legislatíve: Článok 6,27;Informácie o kvalite vonkajšieho ovzdušia a čistejšom ovzduší pre Európu. INSPIRE prioritný dataset (http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/thematicviewer/Domain.action?domain=air_noise&amp;national=false&amp;legislationFilter=false&amp;country=SK)</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:abstract>
        <gmd:pointOfContact>
            <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
                <gmd:individualName>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Ing. Michal Mladý</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:individualName>
                <gmd:organisationName>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Slovenský hydrometeorologický ústav</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:organisationName>                    
                <gmd:role>
                    <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="distributor">distributor</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
                </gmd:role>
            </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        </gmd:pointOfContact>            
        <gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
            <gmd:MD_Keywords>
                <gmd:keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Directive 2008/50/EC</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:keyword>
                <gmd:keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Management zones and agglomerations (Air Quality Directive)</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:keyword>                   
            </gmd:MD_Keywords>
        </gmd:descriptiveKeywords>                          
        <gmd:spatialRepresentationType>
            <gmd:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode codeListValue="vector" codeList="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/codeList.xml#MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode">vector</gmd:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode>
        </gmd:spatialRepresentationType>
        <gmd:language>
            <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="slo">slo</gmd:LanguageCode>
        </gmd:language>
        <gmd:characterSet>
            <gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmx Codelists.xml#MD_ClassificationCode" codeListValue="utf8">utf8</gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode>
        </gmd:characterSet>
        <gmd:topicCategory>
            <gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode>structure</gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode>
        </gmd:topicCategory>
        <gmd:extent>
            <gmd:EX_Extent>
                <gmd:geographicElement>
                    <gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                        <gmd:extentTypeCode>
                            <gco:Boolean>true</gco:Boolean>
                        </gmd:extentTypeCode>
                        <gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>16.83</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                        <gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>22.57</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                        <gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>47.73</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                        <gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                            <gco:Decimal>49.61</gco:Decimal>
                        </gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                    </gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                </gmd:geographicElement>
            </gmd:EX_Extent>
        </gmd:extent>
        <gmd:extent>
            <gmd:EX_Extent>
                <gmd:temporalElement>
                    <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
                        <gmd:extent>
                            <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="ID4tre6b9e-f68e-4a4d-b528-1bh5865ba0fe">
                                <gml:begin>2020-01-01</gml:begin>
                                <gml:end>2020-02-02</gml:end>
                            </gml:TimePeriod>
                        </gmd:extent>
                    </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
                </gmd:temporalElement>
            </gmd:EX_Extent>
        </gmd:extent>            
    </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
</gmd:identificationInfo></gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

The problem is result of XLST transformation of second file which looks like:

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
             xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
             xmlns:gfc="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gfc"
             xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
             xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
             xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr"
             xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"
             xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
             xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/draft-schemas/inspire-md-schemas-temp/apiso-inspire/apiso-inspire.xsd">
<gmd:fileIdentifier xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gco:CharacterString>https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/gmd/42181810/4E93317B0429510DE0530210000A9EA5</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:fileIdentifier>
<gmd:language xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="slo">slo</gmd:LanguageCode>
</gmd:language>
<gmd:parentIdentifier xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gco:CharacterString/>
</gmd:parentIdentifier>
<gmd:hierarchyLevel xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode"
                    codeListValue="dataset">dataset</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
<gmd:contact xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        <gmd:individualName>
```

As you can see i have double namespace declaration for gml but I just need to have just one at root which is same as in XSLT = xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" . Please can you help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"` in your `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag? I don't see it being used anywhere in the stylesheet. -- Also, why does your stylesheet declare version 2.0, but your question is tagged `xslt-1.0`?

Comment: Version 2.0 was mistake....sorry I fixed it to version 1.0. Stylesheet above is just small part. Whole stylesheet has around 1000 lines as well as XML exmaples. But when I remove namespace for GML  from stylesheet result is the same.

Comment: I don't think so, but I cannot show you without a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated xslt and examples.Thanks.

Comment: Please, could someone help me please.